# Grouping rows into a new Pandas DataFrame with one row per group

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have the following DataFrame:

```
from datetime import datetime as dt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd 

inputs = {
    'indicator':[69.88, 85.05, 50.19, 71.08, 44.83, 36.32, 29.42, 44.47, 34.71, 37.91, 32.78, 35.85, 38.98, 23.16, 73.22, 77.77, 49.22, 59.1, 83.38, 88.5, 47.78],
    'short_trade':[0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0],
    'pnl':[-0.0, -0.0, 0.05, -0.06, 0.05, 0.0, 0.0, -0.0, 0.0, -0.0, 0.0, -0.0, -0.0, 0.0, -0.0, -0.0, 0.01, -0.0, -0.0, -0.01, 0.03]
}


_idx = pd.date_range('2018-08-10','2018-09-09',freq='D').to_series()
_idx = _idx[_idx.dt.dayofweek < 5]

data = pd.DataFrame(inputs, index = _idx)
```

My goal is to create a new DataFrame as shown in the screenshot below. Grouping when `short_trade != 0` or `pnl != 0` (it's the same thing).

The first column of the new DataFrame (`trade_n`) is just an ID for each different trade. The new column `pnl` is the sum for each group from the initial DataFrame. Lastly, `duration (D)` is the number of days each trade lasted.

I have found a workaround looping through the DataFrame and checking each row but I'm pretty sure there's a more efficient solution using pandas/numpy.

[image]

Comment: whats excaly the logic of your selection? because you first select 3 rows then 1 then 2

Comment: you want to select the rows with pnl != 0? Plus the previous that was 0

Comment: yes, or short_trade != 0, it's the same. will edit the Q, thanks for point it out

Comment: In your expected output, `pnl` for the second row is `0.01` - shouldn't it be `0.005`, since that's the mean of `0.00` and `0.01`, or should it be clamped to `0.01`.

Comment: @richardec that's just the ```pct_change()``` of prices (returns) that I would get when ```short_trade == 1```. I use that column later to do a ```cumsum()``` and then get the total PnL. I didn't post that part here because I wanted to keep it as simple as possible (I also rounded the ```pnl``` and ```indicator``` numbers for this same purpose)

Comment: Is `duration (D)` the number of items in each group, or the difference of the first date from the last date?

Comment: that would be the number of items in each group

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
s = df \
    .groupby((df['short_trade'].astype(bool) | df['short_trade'].shift(1)).diff().cumsum()) \
    .apply(lambda x: [x.shape[0] - 1, x['pnl'].tolist()]) \
    [::2] \
    .reset_index(drop=True) \
    .tolist()
    
df = pd.DataFrame(s, columns=['duration (D)', 'pnl']) \
    .reset_index() \
    .rename({'index': 'trade_n'}, axis=1)
```

Output:

```
>>> df
   trade_n  duration (D)                        pnl
0        0             3  [-0.0, 0.05, -0.06, 0.05]
1        1             1               [-0.0, 0.01]
2        2             2        [-0.0, -0.01, 0.03]
```

Comment: Your list in `pnl` should be filtered and you have to keep only values where only `pnl` is not 0 and apply the sum on it.

Comment: @Corralien, I left `pnl` as a list because the OP said in the comments that the value of `pnl` in the output df was from `pct_change`, so I suspected it would probably be best to just leave the raw values in there.

Answer (score 1):

IIUC:

```
m = df.short_trade.ne(0) | df.pnl.ne(0)
g = mask.eq(True) & mask.shift().eq(False)

out = df.assign(trade_n=g.cumsum().sub(1)[m]).groupby('trade_n') \
        .agg(**{'pnl': ('pnl', lambda x: sum(x[x.ne(0)])),
                'duration (D)': ('short_trade', lambda x: len(x.ne(0)))}) \
        .reset_index().astype({'trade_n': int})
```

Output:

```
>>> out
   trade_n   pnl  duration (D)
0        0  0.04             4
1        1  0.01             2
2        2  0.02             3
```